# Take an Element of a List which is in a List

Tags: flutter, dart

I know this sounds confusing. I have a List which consists of Lists in these Lists i have always 2 Elements. I want to display the first Element of all Lists. How does it work?

Comment: consider post the sample of the  list you mean.

Comment: go loop the main list and for each element display the first element, where is the programming challenge here?

Answer (score 0):

When you trying to display the list of elements as a group using foreach() loop. By default the list will be displayed in Ascending order only, try that approach once. If you face any issue, please provide your source code, as you trying out to display group of sublists in a Listview. Happy coding